# Storing coordinates in a static array works perfectly when it is stored in a dynamic arary causes the coordinates to break

Tags: arrays, c, memory, ncurses

I have written snake in C using ncurses. The game stores the previous snake locations to calculate the location of the tail. I originally stored the coordinates in a static array but logically it would make more sense to dynamically allocate the array in a dynamic array of the size of the tail for the array. Below is the implementation using a static array.

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define DELAY 100000
#define APPLECOUNT 10

void preventAppleOverlap(int* appleX, int* appleY, int xBound, int yBound);

struct applePositions {
    int xCoordinates[APPLECOUNT];
    int yCoordinates[APPLECOUNT];
};

int main(void) {
    int ch;
    int x = 1, y = 1;
    int maxY = 0, maxX = 0;
    char controls[4] = {'d', 'a', 's', 'w'};
    char controlsInverted[4] = {'a', 'd', 'w', 's'};
    int heading = 0;

    struct applePositions apples;

    // TODO add a dynamiclly allocated array for the tail positions
    int snakeTailSize = 1;
    int snakeTailXPositions[1000];
    int snakeTailYPositions[1000];

    initscr();
    noecho();
    curs_set(FALSE);
    nodelay(stdscr, TRUE);
    getmaxyx(stdscr, maxY, maxX);

    // Generates the initial positions of the apples
    for (int i = 0; i < APPLECOUNT; i++) {
        apples.xCoordinates[i] = rand() % maxX;
        apples.yCoordinates[i] = rand() % maxY;
    }

    preventAppleOverlap(apples.xCoordinates, apples.yCoordinates, maxX, maxY);

    while (1) {
        ch = getch();

        clear();
        char* score = malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);
        sprintf(score, "%i", snakeTailSize - 1);
        // Renders the current score
        mvprintw(0, 0, score);
        // Renders thee head of the snake at the current position
        mvprintw(y, x, "#");
        // Renders the tail of the snale at the previous positions that are stored in the array
        for (int i = 1; i < snakeTailSize; ++i) {
            mvprintw(snakeTailYPositions[i], snakeTailXPositions[i], "#");
        }

        // Rendering the apples
        for (int i = 0; i < APPLECOUNT; ++i) {
            if (x == apples.xCoordinates[i] & y == apples.yCoordinates[i]) {
                apples.xCoordinates[i] = -1;
                apples.yCoordinates[i] = -1;
                snakeTailSize++;
            }
            mvprintw(apples.yCoordinates[i], apples.xCoordinates[i], "@");
        }
        refresh();
        usleep(DELAY);
        // Input handling
        int previousHeading = heading;

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
            if (controls[i] == ch) {
                heading = i;
            }
        }

        // Disables the ability to do instant 180 degree turns 
        if (controls[heading] == controlsInverted[previousHeading]) {
            heading = previousHeading;
        } 
        switch (heading) {
            case 0:
                x += 1;
                break;
            case 1:
                x -= 1;
                break;
            case 2:
                y += 1;
                break;
            case 3:
                y -= 1;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        // Tail logic
        int* snakeTailXPosTemp = malloc(sizeof(int) * snakeTailSize);
        int* snakeTailYPosTemp = malloc(sizeof(int) * snakeTailSize);
        for (int i = 0; i < snakeTailSize; ++i) {
            snakeTailXPosTemp[i] = snakeTailXPositions[i];
            snakeTailYPosTemp[i] = snakeTailYPositions[i];
        }
        snakeTailXPositions[0] = x;
        snakeTailYPositions[0] = y;

        for (int i = 0; i < snakeTailSize - 1; ++i) {
            snakeTailXPositions[i + 1] = snakeTailXPosTemp[i];
            snakeTailYPositions[i + 1] = snakeTailYPosTemp[i];
        }

        // Respawning already eaten apples
        for (int i = 0; i < APPLECOUNT; ++i) {
            if (apples.xCoordinates[i] == -1) {
                apples.xCoordinates[i] = rand() % maxX;
                apples.yCoordinates[i] = rand() % maxY;
            }
        }

        preventAppleOverlap(apples.xCoordinates, apples.yCoordinates, maxX, maxY);

        // End if the snake collides with its own tail
        for (int i = 0; i < snakeTailSize; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < snakeTailSize; ++j) {
                if (snakeTailXPositions[i] == snakeTailXPositions[j] && snakeTailYPositions[i] == snakeTailYPositions[j] && i != j) {
                    endwin();
                    return 0;   
                }
            }
        }
        // End the game if snake is offscreen
        if (x >= maxX || x < 0 || y >= maxY || y < 0) {
            endwin();
            return 0;
        }
        free(score);
        free(snakeTailXPosTemp);
        free(snakeTailYPosTemp);
        
    }
    endwin();
    return 0;
}


void preventAppleOverlap(int* appleX, int* appleY, int xBound, int yBound) {
    int cycleCount = 1;
    int noOverlap = 0;
    while (!noOverlap) {
        cycleCount++;
        noOverlap = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < APPLECOUNT; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < APPLECOUNT; ++j) {
                if (appleX[i] == appleX[j] &&  appleY[i] == appleY[j] && i != j) {
                    noOverlap = 0;
                    appleX[i] = rand() % xBound;
                    appleY[i] = rand() % yBound;
                }
            }
        }
        if (cycleCount == 2) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the non-functioning implementation using a dynamic array

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define DELAY 100000
#define APPLECOUNT 10

void preventAppleOverlap(int* appleX, int* appleY, int xBound, int yBound);

struct applePositions {
    int xCoordinates[APPLECOUNT];
    int yCoordinates[APPLECOUNT];
};

int main(void) {
    int ch;
    int x = 1, y = 1;
    int maxY = 0, maxX = 0;
    char controls[4] = {'d', 'a', 's', 'w'};
    char controlsInverted[4] = {'a', 'd', 'w', 's'};
    int heading = 0;

    struct applePositions apples;

    // TODO add a dynamiclly allocated array for the tail positions
    int snakeTailSize = 1;
    int* snakeTailXPositions = malloc(sizeof(int) * 1000);
    int* snakeTailYPositions = malloc(sizeof(int) * 1000);

    initscr();
    noecho();
    curs_set(FALSE);
    nodelay(stdscr, TRUE);
    getmaxyx(stdscr, maxY, maxX);

    // Generates the initial positions of the apples
    for (int i = 0; i < APPLECOUNT; i++) {
        apples.xCoordinates[i] = rand() % maxX;
        apples.yCoordinates[i] = rand() % maxY;
    }

    preventAppleOverlap(apples.xCoordinates, apples.yCoordinates, maxX, maxY);

    while (1) {
        ch = getch();

        clear();
        char* score = malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);
        sprintf(score, "%i", snakeTailSize - 1);
        // Renders the current score
        mvprintw(0, 0, score);
        // Renders thee head of the snake at the current position
        mvprintw(y, x, "#");
        // Renders the tail of the snale at the previous positions that are stored in the array
        for (int i = 1; i < snakeTailSize; ++i) {
            mvprintw(snakeTailYPositions[i], snakeTailXPositions[i], "#");
        }

        // Rendering the apples
        for (int i = 0; i < APPLECOUNT; ++i) {
            if (x == apples.xCoordinates[i] & y == apples.yCoordinates[i]) {
                apples.xCoordinates[i] = -1;
                apples.yCoordinates[i] = -1;
                snakeTailSize++;
            }
            mvprintw(apples.yCoordinates[i], apples.xCoordinates[i], "@");
        }
        refresh();
        usleep(DELAY);
        // Input handling
        int previousHeading = heading;

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
            if (controls[i] == ch) {
                heading = i;
            }
        }

        // Disables the ability to do instant 180 degree turns 
        if (controls[heading] == controlsInverted[previousHeading]) {
            heading = previousHeading;
        } 
        switch (heading) {
            case 0:
                x += 1;
                break;
            case 1:
                x -= 1;
                break;
            case 2:
                y += 1;
                break;
            case 3:
                y -= 1;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        // Tail logic
        int* snakeTailXPosTemp = malloc(sizeof(int) * snakeTailSize);
        int* snakeTailYPosTemp = malloc(sizeof(int) * snakeTailSize);
        for (int i = 0; i < snakeTailSize; ++i) {
            snakeTailXPosTemp[i] = snakeTailXPositions[i];
            snakeTailYPosTemp[i] = snakeTailYPositions[i];
        }
        snakeTailXPositions[0] = x;
        snakeTailYPositions[0] = y;

        for (int i = 0; i < snakeTailSize - 1; ++i) {
            snakeTailXPositions[i + 1] = snakeTailXPosTemp[i];
            snakeTailYPositions[i + 1] = snakeTailYPosTemp[i];
        }

        // Respawning already eaten apples
        for (int i = 0; i < APPLECOUNT; ++i) {
            if (apples.xCoordinates[i] == -1) {
                apples.xCoordinates[i] = rand() % maxX;
                apples.yCoordinates[i] = rand() % maxY;
            }
        }

        preventAppleOverlap(apples.xCoordinates, apples.yCoordinates, maxX, maxY);

        // End if the snake collides with its own tail
        for (int i = 0; i < snakeTailSize; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < snakeTailSize; ++j) {
                if (snakeTailXPositions[i] == snakeTailXPositions[j] && snakeTailYPositions[i] == snakeTailYPositions[j] && i != j) {
                    free(snakeTailXPositions);
                    free(snakeTailYPositions);
                    endwin();
                    return 0;   
                }
            }
        }
        // End the game if snake is offscreen
        if (x >= maxX || x < 0 || y >= maxY || y < 0) {
            free(snakeTailXPositions);
            free(snakeTailYPositions);
            endwin();
            return 0;
        }
        free(score);
        free(snakeTailXPosTemp);
        free(snakeTailYPosTemp);
        
    }
    endwin();
    return 0;
}


void preventAppleOverlap(int* appleX, int* appleY, int xBound, int yBound) {
    int cycleCount = 1;
    int noOverlap = 0;
    while (!noOverlap) {
        cycleCount++;
        noOverlap = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < APPLECOUNT; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < APPLECOUNT; ++j) {
                if (appleX[i] == appleX[j] &&  appleY[i] == appleY[j] && i != j) {
                    noOverlap = 0;
                    appleX[i] = rand() % xBound;
                    appleY[i] = rand() % yBound;
                }
            }
        }
        if (cycleCount == 2) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

While the dynamic implementation does not use realloc to resize the array the size of the tail. It is static so that I could debug this issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Compile with `-fsanitize=address` Your first example (static) has a memory leak for the `malloc` that it does. The dynamic version performs identically to the static and works the same. The dynamic version correctly does a `free` for the second set of `malloc` calls. So, you may have something else going on. AFAICT, both versions work identically, as tested on my system.

Comment: First, run it with something like `Valgrind` and fix all the reported errors if any.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score -1):

I experimented with your dynamic implementation and changing to pointer incrementation for your dynamic arrays seemed to address the situation.

In lieu of the following code.

```
for (int i = 0; i < snakeTailSize; ++i) {
        snakeTailXPosTemp[i] = snakeTailXPositions[i];
        snakeTailYPosTemp[i] = snakeTailYPositions[i];
    }
```

Using the value of "i" as an increment for the snake tail location and incrementing the pointer location seemed to work.  Here is the revised code.

```
for (int i = 0; i < snakeTailSize; ++i) {
    snakeTailXPosTemp[i] = *(snakeTailXPositions + i);
    snakeTailYPosTemp[i] = *(snakeTailYPositions + i);
}
```

I am not too experienced with simulating array indexing via shifting around the pointer, but you might look at this link for further information about using dynamic arrays.

[Dynamic Arrays](https://www.scaler.com/topics/c/dynamic-array-in-c/)

It seems to intimate that accessing the various array elements is done via adjusting the pointer increment.  Hope that helps.

Regards.

Comment: These two snippets are exactly the same. The two notations are equivalent, and it cannot possibly be a source of any issue. An answer should contain a root-cause, an explanation and a way to fix it.

Comment: No.  They are slightly different.  The first snippet has "snakeTailXPositions[i]" and "snakeTailYPositions[i]" (using and index); whereas, the second snippet has "*(snakeTailXPositions + i)" and "*(snakeTailYPositions + i)" performing a pointer increment.  When I changed the code from the former to the latter, I got different results in running the code.  And when I changed to the latter, the program displayed the snake movement in the identical manner as the first iteration of the program.

Comment: From the [C standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.1p2): *The definition of the subscript operator `[]` is that `E1[E2]` is identical to `(*((E1)+(E2)))`*. So they are exactly the same. The fact that you got different behaviors between two compilations is only telling that the program has undefined behavior somewhere.

Comment: Okay.  I won't disagree.  I must have had some undefined quirk that gave me a different result prior to trying out that tweak.